# Does gas optimization only apply to leading zeros in contract addresses?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, gas, addresses, optimization

I couldn't find any solid information on this. From assembly perspective clearly

```
PUSH2 0xC0FE
```

for a two byte address `0xC0FE` requires less memory than a full `PUSH20`, but I could swear I also read *any* amount of zeros in the address no matter the position would help reducing gas costs. If that is true, how can it be explained?